# AngularJS + Jasmine Noob: How to access $scope in spec?

Tags: angularjs

This is my first time testing using Jasmine. I'm having trouble accessing the $scope variables in the spec. I have a failing test:

```
mysite ProductsDetailCtrl sets hey
  Expected undefined to be 1.
    Error: Expected undefined to be 1.
```

spec:

```
//= require helpers/load-angular-mysite-module
//= require products/controllers/products_detail_controller

describe('mysite', function() {
  var $rootScope, $scope, $controller;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('mysite');
  });

  describe('ProductsDetailCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;    // don't really
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();   // understand what's
      $controller = _$controller_;  // going on in this function

      controller = $controller('ProductsDetailCtrl', {
        '$rootScope': $rootScope,
        '$scope': $scope
      });
    }));

    it('sets hey', function() {
      expect($rootScope.hey).toBe(1);
    });
  });

});
```

controller:

```
app.controller('ProductsDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
  $scope.hey = 1;
 ....
```

Could someone explain to me how I would access the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to check for the property `hey`in your `$scope` not in the `$rootScope`:

```
describe('mysite', function() {
  var scope, ProductsDetailCtrl;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('mysite');
  });

  describe('ProductsDetailCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      // Create a mock scope for your controller.
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      // Initialize the controller with the mocked scope.
      ProductsDetailCtrl = $controller('ProductsDetailCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
      });
    }));

    it('sets hey', function() {
      expect(scope.hey).toBe(1);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: You did use it. You called `$new()` on it to create a new `$scope` that you passed to your controller. You also tried to pass `$rootScope` to the controller but since the controller does not use it that didn't really do anything.

Comment: You just need to call `$rootScope.$new()` to instantiate a new scope. But you don't need to use it anywhere else, unless you use `$rootScope` in your `ProductsDetailCtrl`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code of how your spec definition should look ;)